# UINavigationController won't push other view controllers?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

So I created a UINavigationController in my app's delegate and initialized it with my RootViewController instance. The UINavigationController was added as a subview of the app's UIWindow. (My RVC has a custom initializer if that matters.)

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
              _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

              _viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithPath:@"/private/var/mobile/"];
              _viewController.title = @"mobile";

              UINavigationController *nav1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController] autorelease];

              //This part I'm not sure about as well
              [_window addSubview:nav1.view];
              [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return 0;
    }
```

With that information, I'm trying to push another instance of RVC onto the Navigation Stack from an UITableView like so:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
              //I've tried it without the if statement as well
              if(indexPath.section == 0){
                      RootViewController *detailView = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithPath:launchDirectory];
                      detailView.title = relativeDirectory;
                      [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

As another note, my RVC tableview's datasource and delegate have been set to "self".

My question is: Why does the view stay the same even though I select a row on the table?
The table doesn't push to a new one and I still see the same cell contents after selecting a row. In other words, nothing happens...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation controller is likely `nil`, which means that your `-autorelease` is a little too much.  Typically, Navigation Controllers persist until the dealloc method of the delegate is called, so release it there.

Comment: setRootViewController isn't in my UIWindow class. I'm using SDK 3 btw for compatibility.

Comment: Then ignore the first part.  The second part still holds true.

Comment: It's a new instance though. A new variable. Which is why I created a custom initializer for it. The custom initializer creates the array from which the table is populated. The -second- RVC instance has a different array than the first. And I read that you can push different instances of the same class. Kinda like using multiple UIAlertViews. UIViewControllers are no different. Just to test this theory, I created a DetailView class identical to the RVC class. Still wasn't able to push the DetailView class from parent view controller (RVC).

Comment: Then your navigationController is somehow nil.

Comment: Anyway to get around that by any chance?

Comment: NSLog() it to make sure, then if it is nil, remove the autorelease call.

Comment: It was nil. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, my friend!